# http response - domain does not exist?

Tags: http, response

Is there any http header response code for domain name does not exist? similar to 404 not found?

Just wondering if it is possible or any other better suggestions to achieve this would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the domain does not exist, then the HTTP client will not be able to connect to any HTTP server, and thus you will not get *any* HTTP response at all, because the lower layer protocols cannot connect to provide the conduit for the higher level HTTP connection.

Comment: means if my request gets a timeout or no response, I should assume either the domain does not exist or there was a problem?

Comment: That is a fairly open-ended and safe assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  That's a function of DNS, not HTTP.